# How to do a ctypedef with fused dtype

Tags: cython

I have the following typedef

```
ctypedef fused sa_t:
    np.int32_t
    np.int64_t
```

In a function with a `sa_t` argument, I have the following declaration

```
cdef vector[pair[sa_t, sa_t]] count
```

I would like to make `pair[sa_t, sa_t]` more accessible.

However, I cannot do a `ctypedef` in the function and my attempts to do one outside don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following demo works fine(Cython version 0.29.13), does it give you some hints?

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.pair cimport pair
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef fused sa_t:
    np.int32_t
    np.int64_t


ctypedef pair[sa_t, sa_t] sa_pair_t
ctypedef vector[sa_pair_t] sa_pairs_t

cdef void func(sa_t value):
    cdef sa_pairs_t sa_pairs
    sa_pairs.push_back(pair[sa_t, sa_t](value, value))
    print(sa_pairs)


func[np.int32_t](1)  # print [(1, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like what I'm currently doing. My problem is that I would like to use `sa_pair_t(value, value)` instead of `pair[sa_t, sa_t](value, value)`. If `sa_t` is not a fused type, it works.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a limitation of Cython, since fused type and c++ template are not the same creature. Cython needs `pair[sa_t, sa_t](value, value)` to compile,  I havn't any idea of the cython compiler.